# argocd deploy a kubernetes manifest

Tags: kubernetes, manifest, argocd

I cannot find absolutely anything related to deploying kubernetes manifests with argocd.
It looks like even google is filtering our non relevant questions as it shows pages of how to deploy argocd instead of how to deploy WITH argocd ...

I have to deploy a manifest file to remote clusters and would like to use argocd. When I try to created from the web ui I can see the remote repository, where I have multiple helm charts separated by directories, but when I try to select the directory that contains a manifest argocd is not displaying it in the dropdown menu

Please can anyone help me with some hidden documentation regarding this ?

Comment: Have you even read the ArgoCD documentation? The idea is that you put this manifest in a Git repo and configure ArgoCD to look at this repo. You need to create what is called a `Application` in ArgoCD which itself will need to be part of a `Project`. You can start with the UI but the real power is in doing this declaratively.

Comment: As I mentioned before, I am using argocd and am very familiar with deploying charts from remote repositories. Maybe you have not even read my question :) @GaëlJ. Helm charts work as expected, but simple manifests, like f.e. one single yaml file containing k8s resources nested are not visible to argocd when I "create app" -> source -> select repo url -> select path but the directory is not visible in the dropdown menu.

Comment: And by directory I mean, I see the helm charts directories, can select them, but cannot find the directory where I saved the manifest (single yaml file). And yes, it is located in that branch

Comment: Well, maybe show us what your UI look's like. I 'ever use the UI to create apps on ArgoCD. On top of my head, if your directory contains both a helm chart and other files, the Helm chart might have precedence.

Comment: I have created another directory outside of the helm chart directory on same level and still it is invisible to argocd. Maybe argo cannot deploy manifests but only helm charts that it transforms to manifest ... I am preparing helm chart from the manifest because I don't have time to test more unfortunately. I also posted on argo gihub page but no answer. Maybe I am the only human being that ever tried to deploy a manifest with argocd. Thanks for the helm @GaëlJ

Comment: No.. I deploy only manifests. But I use the declarative approach. So if you can't provide a snapshot of what you get, hard to help.

Comment: https://argo-cd.readthedocs.io/en/stable/user-guide/directory/

Answer (score 0):

Look here:

[https://argo-cd.readthedocs.io/en/stable/operator-manual/declarative-setup/#:~:text=See-,application.yaml,-for%20additional%20fields](https://argo-cd.readthedocs.io/en/stable/operator-manual/declarative-setup/#:%7E:text=See-,application.yaml,-for%20additional%20fields)

https://argo-cd.readthedocs.io/en/stable/operator-manual/declarative-setup/

You have to create Project, Cluster and Application.

In the links above you can find how to do as code.

Comment: Thanks a lot @glv but I am talking about manifest, like one yaml file, f.e. (https://codefresh.io/learn/software-deployment/kubernetes-deployment-yaml/).
Like you would execute "kubectl apply -f name_of_the_manifest.yaml"

Comment: Not a helm chart as that is already working as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Just by pointing the application to a Git repository, to a folder, or even to a specific file, it'll be deployed.
Let me give you an example:
[external-secret application pointing to a single manifest as one of the sources](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zUeoY.png)
That is the definition of the application's sources. One is the Helm Chart, but the other one is a single resource where I'm adding a single and unique Kubernetes manifest [btw, several things were redacted due to compliance with my company :D]:
[image showing contents for secret-store-kv.yaml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DW3fE.png)
And that will make Argo deploy it. [check how it has an annotation to do a PostSync, as I need ExternalSecret's CRDs deployed for this manifest to work, you can use SyncWaves as well].

Cheers!